# Multiple criteria on the same column

Tags: sql, oracle

How do I search with multiple criteria on the same column.
T1 has the IDs.

T2:

```
ID    T1_ID(FK)   Value
 1    1        Apple
 2    1        Orange
 3    1        Kiwi
 4    2        Orange
 5    2        Kiwi
 6    3        Pear
 7    3        Berry
 8    3        Orange
 9    4        Apple
 10   5        Apple
 11   5        Apple
 12   5        Kiwi
```

Output:

```
T2_ID(FK)   Value
1        Apple
1        Orange
1        Kiwi

select t2.t1_id, t2.value
from t1, t2
where t1.id = t2.id
and t2.value in ('Apple','Orange','Kiwi')
group by t1.id having count(t2.value)=3
```

Is this query correct? Doesn't it also bring t2_id = 5 because #5 matches with apple and kiwi  although apple is duplicate?

Comment: How would we know if the query is correct? You posted inputs (perfect!) and some code that apparently doesn't do what you want (also helpful). You did NOT state the requirement. What do you need to return? All the original rows, only for those T1_ID which appear with Apple, Orange and Kiwi at least once? Exactly once? Exactly those three and none other? ALL these possible interpretations are consistent with what you posted. So: What is the requirement?

Comment: @mathguy : all Apple, Orange and Kiwi, 3 values atleast once. My issue is from my current query, if I do a value =3, it doesn't work as some records may have duplicates, e.g: ID =5.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to join `t1` and you need `COUNT(DISTINCT column_name)`:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e22007/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE t2 (ID, T1_ID, Value ) AS
SELECT 1,    1,        'Apple' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,    1,        'Orange' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3,    1,        'Kiwi' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4,    2,        'Orange' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5,    2,        'Kiwi' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6,    3,        'Pear' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7,    3,        'Berry' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 8,    3,        'Orange' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 9,    4,        'Apple' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10,   5,        'Apple' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11,   5,        'Apple' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 12,   5,        'Kiwi' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select t1_id,
       LISTAGG( value, ',' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY value ) As "values"
from   t2
where  value in ('Apple','Orange','Kiwi')
group by t1_id
having count( DISTINCT value) = 3
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e22007/1/0)**:

```
| T1_ID |            values |
|-------|-------------------|
|     1 | Apple,Kiwi,Orange |
```

**Query 2**:

You can also do it using collections:

```
CREATE TYPE STRINGLIST IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(10);
/


SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t1_id,
         CAST( COLLECT( value ORDER BY value ) AS STRINGLIST ) AS "values"
  FROM   t2
  GROUP BY t1_id
)
WHERE  STRINGLIST( 'Apple', 'Kiwi', 'Orange' ) SUBMULTISET OF "values"
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e22007/1/1)**:

```
| T1_ID |            values |
|-------|-------------------|
|     1 | Apple,Kiwi,Orange |
```

Comment: What requirement is this trying to solve? When the OP doesn't post a requirement, it would help to state what you assumed if you will offer an Answer anyway. For example: if T1_ID also had another row with `'Banana'` - does that need to be concatenated in the `values` string too? (Not clear at all from the OP's requirement, even if otherwise the LISTAGG was required.)